# I want to remove something off a site using css

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to remove icons from my website using CSS

[image]

You can see it here https://www.stormyark.de/hksv

I uploaded the website files at [github](https://github.com/stormyark/stormyark.de)

I already tried to set the "width=0" of the icons but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

use `display: none;` on the class of the element you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways of hiding an element in CSS.

```css
display: none;
```

This will remove the element from the DOM

```css
opacity: 0;
```

This will hide the element.

```css
visibility:hidden;
```

This will hide the element.

Note: Opacity and visibility does not remove the element.

Comment: Thank you, but if i type <div class="controls show" style="Display: none;Display: none;visibility:hidden;"> i does show the icons anyways...

Comment: why did you type display:none; two times?

Comment: What you can do is create a css file and attach it to you html using link tag in head if you dont know.
In your CSS file type

.controls{
display:none;
}

Comment: I typed two times display:none; by accident
But your suggestion doesnt work either...
I put .controls{ display:none; } in in control.css
and in html <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stormyark.de/assets/css/control.css" type="text/css">